# shell script weird file name when concatenate the date

Tags: linux, shell, command

i am doing a simple task, to backup a folder to .tgz format.

Here is my script:

```
noww=$(date +'%m_%d_%Y') 
file_extension=".tgz" 
archive_file="pppbackup$noww$file_extension" 
echo "date:$noww" 
echo "start backing up to $archive_file"
sudo tar -zcvf $archive_file /opt/pppaddon
```

I got the file but very weird name.
Do a ls command, the name appears with "??" at the end.
pppbackup04_22_2015.tgz?? 
I don't know what is this to google.
How can i fix this? I can't download the file as well

Comment: Can I suggest that you adopt a more sensible date format, like '%Y-%m-%d'?  It sorts so much more easily than this weird field order that seems to be used only in the United States.

Comment: yes, does that cause the "??" at the end of file?

Comment: Nope, but there are multiple problems with your shell script that could contribute to odd behaviour. Separating commands onto their own lines is a good start.

Comment: (Not your current problem) You should use `noww=$(date +'%Y-%m_%d')`, that way you can easy sort/manipulate your backups. And people from Holland don't get confused mixing up the mmddyyyy and ddmmyyyy notation.

Comment: We would like to know what characters are hidden. Can you check with `ls pppbackup04_22_2015.tg* | od -cx` ?

Comment: I found it out , it's newline in windows \n

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Before the question was edited

This line:

```
archive_file="pppbackup$noww$file_extension" echo "date:$noww"
```

creates an environment variable `$archive_file` for as long as it takes to execute the `echo` command (or overrides its previous value), but that's all.  Once the `echo` completes, the next line executes as if you never assigned to `$archive_file`.

Split the line:

```
archive_file="pppbackup$noww$file_extension"
echo "date:$noww"
```

You should run the command/script under `bash -x` to see what's going on.  You could also add `echo "archive_file=[$archive_file]"` before and after the assignment line.  You might be picking up an erroneous value you created some time ago.  Since your backup is only dated — it doesn't include the time stamp — you might have created the variable by accident a while ago and not noticed that it was bogus before.

#### After the question was edited

If it is still a problem after you've split the faulty line, run the revised script under `bash -x` and pipe the output and error output to your preferred tool for making non-printable characters visible.  IN extremis, use:

```
bash -x yourscript.sh 2>&1 | od -c
```

but any program that makes funny characters legible will do.  You can find out what the `??` really represents.  And then we can debug what you're seeing better.

Comment: that's because i copy paste to this site, they are in two lines, still got weird ??

Comment: See my updated answer.  And please make sure you post the exact code that's causing trouble. It is really frustrating to provide an answer to the code that's shown only to find that the code that's shown is not the code that's causing the trouble.

Comment: I wrote the script in notepad ++ and upload over. I did bash -x and saw \r \n after file extension. it's for new line in notepad. Will this be the issue? How can i fix that?

Comment: Did you see `\r\n` or `/r/n`?  The `\r` is a cause of troubles.  It's a carriage return rather than a line feed or newline.  It's normal to see those at the end of a line on Windows, but abnormal on Unix (including Linux).  The `\n` is a newline.  It isn't immediately obvious how you'd get a newline into the archive file name.  The `$(…)` notation drops trailing newlines (but not carriage returns).  Can you drop the 'v' from `tar -cvzf` and then post the output of `bash -x yourscript.sh 2>&1 | od -c`?  Then we can maybe see what's happening when?  Without that, people can't help so easily.

Comment: Tip: to convert the EOL easily, use command `dos2unix` or notepad++, go to: Edit -> EOL conversion ->  Choose Unix style. that will clean the \r problem.